# Can you configure the port to use for IMAP in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, email, imap, macos

The outgoing mail server has a field for a custom port number, but I don't see one for the incoming mail server (IMAP). Is there a way to set it?

I'm testing an email server. I know this is not something one does normally.

Mail 11.4, macOS 10.13.5.

[image]

Comment: Don't think you can in mail.app, have you tried Thunderbird (by Mozilla)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck "Automatically manage connection settings" below the "Host Name" field. The port number field should appear.

[image: screen capture]